# Adding multiple numbers with multiple clicks to a value in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

In Visual Basic I want to add multiple numbers with multiple clicks to my value so I used this method but it doens't go as ordered
this is how its supposed to display the result 1 -> 3 -> 7 -> 15 -> 31 -> 63 -> 127 
but it goes like this 1 -> 3 -> 11 and stops here

I think when my value reaches 6 it doesn't go further.

Here is my method:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim a As Integer = 0
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Label1.Text = (Str(a))

        Select Case (a + 1) * 2 - 1


            Case 0
                a += 1
            Case 1
                a += 2
            Case 2
                a += 4
            Case 3
                a += 8
            Case 4
                a += 16
            Case 5
                a += 32
            Case 6
                a += 64


        End Select

    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Replace the `Select Case` block with `a = (a + 1) * 2 - 1`?

Comment: tried it, that doesnt work

Comment: I suggest you show more of your code then - for instance, your current posted code doesn't show how you are setting `a` so that might be an issue.

Comment: I edited my code and now you can see my whole code

Comment: If the result of `(a + 1) * 2 - 1` is anything but 0 through 6 then nothing's going to happen, is that your intention?

Comment: no i replaced Select Case a with Select Case (a + 1) * 2 - 1 nothing changed

Comment: You don't even need `Select Case` here. Just put your value in a cell (let's say `A1`), and when you click your button change the cell's value to itself times 2 + 1.

Comment: can you write a full example?

Comment: That looks like VB.NET code, so why the VBA tag?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Comment: what i want is that when i first click the button add 1 to my value on second click add 2 to my value at third click add 4 to my value an so on

Comment: Oh I didn't even notice this was VB.net and not VBA. Anyways, how are you getting your value for a? It's always set to 0 it looks like?

Comment: at first yes its set to 0 but as goes on we add multiple number to it

Comment: @hadiBastanfar Where in your code do you add numbers to it?

Comment: Case 0
            a += 1

        Case 1
            a += 2

        Case 2
            a += 4

Comment: Replace your entire `Select Case` **block** with `a = (a + 1) * 2 - 1`, don't just change it to be `Select Case (a + 1) * 2 - 1`.

Comment: Those downvotes are telling you that you need to ask better questions: see [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

The following should work for you:

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim a As Integer = 0
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Label1.Text = Str(a)

        a = (a + 1) * 2 - 1

    End Sub

End Class
```

Note: You might like to change the order of the two statements - it depends on whether you want to display `0` the first time through, or whether you want to display `1` the first time.